# Python Selenium --- how to support Gmail compose multiple New message under one Tab with customized subject and body content (Gmail)

Tags: python, selenium

I am fresh new for Python and Selenium learning

I've written script as below to compose 1 message and then send it

Expected: i want to compose 50+ message under one tab and with customized subject and body content

My problem: those new messages frames have the same class name , how can i  identify each

thanks

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome(exepath)
browser.get(url)

elem = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
elem.send_keys(user)

browser.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span').click()
time.sleep(2)


elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
elem.send_keys(pwd)
time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span').click()
time.sleep(10)


browser.find_element_by_xpath (".//*[text()= 'COMPOSE']").click()
time.sleep(2)

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("vO")
elem.send_keys(to)
time.sleep(3)

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("aoT")
elem.send_keys(subject)
time.sleep(3)

#browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Send']").click()
```

Comment: We can't really respond to your question since we don't know the layout of the site nor the site to check it out.

Comment: <iframe id="apiproxyc78d7cd9fa137ec4fc6a851895e649a38ee35fe00.3417781223" name="apiproxyc78d7cd9fa137ec4fc6a851895e649a38ee35fe00.3417781223" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -100px; display: none;" src="https://clients6.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.yK0z3MKtgaU.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo-SafOYj4n3budMysbWxppU-lxJeg#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com&amp;rpctoken=578920204" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></iframe>

Comment: The iframeid and name are same for Gmail compose multiple New message

Comment: @AfloroaieRobert any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each frame has it's own div with identifier?
You can get all of this frames:

```
frames = browser.find_element(<selector>)
for frame in frames:
    # your code here, you can use XPATH only selectors to search in parent element, just use '.' at the beggining of each, example method is below
```

Method to get each child element:

```
_xpath_test_elem_parent = ".//*{0}"

def parent_element(self, parent: WebElement, locator: str):
    """
    Returns ``WebElement`` instance for the given data-test locator and
    parent element

    :param parent: Parent element
    :param locator: Data-test locator for element
    :return: WebElement instance
    """
    logger.info('Searching for element with '
               '"{0}"'.format(locator))
    elem = parent.find_element_by_xpath(
        self._xpath_test_elem_parent.format(locator))
    return elem
```

Comment: <iframe id="apiproxyc78d7cd9fa137ec4fc6a851895e649a38ee35fe00.3417781223" name="apiproxyc78d7cd9fa137ec4fc6a851895e649a38ee35fe00.3417781223" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -100px; display: none;" src="https://clients6.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.yK0z3MKtgaU.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo-SafOYj4n3budMysbWxppU-lxJeg#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com&amp;rpctoken=578920204" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></iframe>

Comment: The iframeid and name are same for Gmail compose multiple New message